# Powershell: Error while creating a PSCredential object using New-Object cmdlet

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting, powershell-cmdlet

I am using PS Version 5.0

When trying to create a PSCredential object using New-Object cmdlet, I was getting this error:

```
New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "PSCredential" and the argument count: "2".
```

My PS Code is as below:

```
[string][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] $secureStringPwd = "pass"

$secureStringPwd = $secureStringPwd|ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

$creds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "svcacct", $secureStringPwd
```

As you can see I am converting the password to secure string but still getting an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way

```
[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] $secureStringPwd = "pass"

$secureStringPwd = $secureStringPwd|ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

($creds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "svcacct", $secureStringPwd)

# Results

UserName                     Password
--------                     --------
svcacct  System.Security.SecureString
```

Or this way

```
[string][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$secureStringPwd = "pass"
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $secureStringPwd -AsPlainText -Force
($creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("username", $secpasswd))


# Results
UserName                     Password
--------                     --------
username System.Security.SecureString
```